# Show multiple images in bootstrapp model pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a logic to show single image in model pop-up, but now I'm trying to show list multiple images the same model pop-up. How can I achieve that?
Here is my working code for single image.

```js
$(document).on("click", "a[name='lnkViews']", function() {
  var myImageId = $(this).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("
    ImagesView ", "
    Controller ")",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      Id: myImageId
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

      document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.data;

      $('#gardenImage').modal('show');

    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="gardenImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gardenImageLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="border-color:transparent !important">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="border-color:transparent !important">

        <img class="center-block" id="ItemPreview" src="" alt="" />

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger center-block" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('img.center-block').each(function() { $(this).src = 'image path' })`

Comment: Off topic: You'll find your code more maintainable if you stick with either jquery or vanilla js.  Using `document.getElementById` then immediately `$("#..")` is just messy and confusing.

Comment: Is there as reason you can't add a second `<img>` tag?  then `$("#ItemPreview1")[0].src = ..img1src..` `$("#ItemPreview2")[0].src = ..img2src..`

Comment: @freedomn-m As we don't know how many images we may get. so how can we add multiple tags before hand?

Comment: @PrudhviBharadwaj good point.  Can you add the `<img>` tags dynamically?  `$("#gardenImage .modal-body").append("<img src='" + data.data[i] + "' />");`  Need to know where you are getting your "multiple images" from to be more specific.

Comment: @freedomn-m  I'm getting data in success response. ( data.data ).

Comment: Your `data.data` is a single bytestream of multiple images?